# Self Host SignalR in windows 10

Tags: iis, signalr, windows-10

Hi iam making an app for which i have already completed the UI part and is currently a asp.net MVC project. for which i use the local IIS to debug. A part of the project that we are using uses signalr for device that connect to the system running the app.

Local IIS on windows 10 PRO limits the max connection to 10. Which is not something we can do away with.

The solution that seems promising is to make a signalR self host. 
as the link states here 
https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/435

if the app is not using any part of the inbuilt IIS then there is no limit of the maximum connection.

The problem that im facing is that there is not help available anywhere related to it. and i want to be sure before getting to start with signalR self host about the maximum connections that it will be able to hold on a system running windows 10 Home / Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without the available help. I converted my application to SignalR Self Host and tested it. ANd seems there is no Connection Limit even on Windows 10 Home version. So the system is working fine.
@Lex Li i think you should test again with windows 10.
So the conclusion is that IIS is actually the culprit for the max connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in IIS Express.
Right click your web project and go to properties.
On the Web tab, note the Project Url with port (http://localhost:12345)
That is the url it will be running in IIS Express.
Then start your site to fire it up in IIS Express. I right click the web and select View, but you could also start debugging.
Once it is running in IIS Express you can see the icon in the taskbar by the clock and manage all sites running in IIS Express there.

Comment: Your answer is not at all related the question i asked

Comment: IIS Express doesn't limit the # of connections. Sorry thought it was obvious.