# Windows 10 Maximum TCP-IP Connection Limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, iis, signalr, windows-10

Hi i have made a windows 10 app. That typically hosts a website inside using IIS Hostable Web Core. The App uses Asp.Net Web API OData and SignalR to connect to the devices in the local network.

The App should be able to connect to atleast 300 devices at once. 
I have hit the maximum connection limit in window systems. Currently im being able to connect to 10 devices maximum on a windows PRO System.

On reading about the issue i came across many articles stating that HTTP.sys an internal window driver is responsible for this connection limit. Which meant if i can bypass the http.sys i can bypass the maximum connection limit.

Two places from where i could get help was
1. Kestrel
2. NodeJS

kestrel being a server for .net code would require me to update whole of my code to .net 1.0 core which isnt a very viable solution

edje.js an opensoure project allows me to run my OWIN application inside expressjs which has its own http stack and hence does not use http.sys so is free from the connection limit enforced by the windows.

My problem is that there is no more help available any where else. 
Is it correct that if iam able to get it working using expressjs as the owin server then ill be able to bypass the connection limit?

Comment: If you want to support so many connections, use Windows Server.

Comment: Using windows server. Will Add additional resources to be installed before the app installs

Comment: There are bound to be some additional resources used since W Server will have a number of management and security features on by default. You can probably tune this to some extent by turning off features and services.

Comment: i want to make an app that the user can download and run in the local area network. and asking the user to buy a windows server license and then install the app will be a big no no

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802347/self-host-signalr-in-windows-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 10: Windows 10 vs Windows Server 2016, Number of connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670499/iis-10-windows-10-vs-windows-server-2016-number-of-connections)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely hitting the Windows socket limit (different from HTTP).  From the following website: https://docs.uptimesoftware.com/display/KB/Increasing+Windows+TCP+socket+limits

> To increase the Windows socket limits and allow sockets to be freed up more quickly, create 2 keys in the Windows registry using regedit.
>
> Within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, create these 2 DWORD values:
>
> MaxUserPort: this value will increase the number of ephemeral ports that can by dynamically allocated to clients.  Set the value to any decimal between 5000 and 65534.  Higher counts will allow more concurrent sockets to be available to Uptime Infrastructure Monitor.
>
> TcpTimedWaitDelay: this value will reduce the length of time that a connection stays in the TIME_WAIT state when the connection is being closed.  While a connection is in the TIME_WAIT state, the socket pair cannot be re-used.  Lower values allow sockets to be released more quickly for re-use by Uptime Infrastructure Monitor.  Set the value to a decimal number between 30 and 240.  Note that you will need to restart the computer for the system changes to take effect.  For more information, please refer to Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion on the Microsoft website.